# error con numpy File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in mean

Tags: python, funciones, numpy, scipy

Estoy intentando realizar un programa con menu que me permita realizar cálculos estadísticos mediante los datos que desee ingresar el usuario. Al querer compilarlo únicamente me solicita el ingreso de que cantidad de datos deseo calcular y a continuación me muestra la lista con los números ingresados pero no logra calcularse ninguna de las demás medidas aritméticas

Por medio de esta función solicito e ingreso de los datos`
En esta función quiero calcular algunas de las medidas artimeticas con los datos incluidos en la lista pero al intentar compilarlos no los reconoce

````
def ingreso_valores():
global datos
datos = []
n = int(input("¿Cuantos valores desea ingresar?: "))
for i in range(n):
    dato = input("valor: ")
    datos.append(dato)
print("Los valores ingresados son: ", datos)```

def calculo_media():       
media = np.mean(datos)
print("La media aritmetica es: ", media)

def calculo_mediana():
mediana = np.median(datos)
print("La mediana es: ", mediana)

def calculo_moda():
moda = stats.mode(datos)
print("La moda es: ", moda)

def calculo_varianza():
varianza = np.var(datos)
print("La varianza es: ", varianza)

def calculo_desviacion():
desviacion_estandar = np.std(datos)
print("La desviacion estandar es: ", desviacion_estandar)```
````

Este seria el menu por el cual el usuario elegiria la opcion deseada

````
    menu()
    seleccion = input("Seleccione una opcion >>: ")
    if seleccion == '0':
        ingreso_valores()
    elif seleccion == '1':
        calculo_media()
    elif seleccion == '2':
        calculo_mediana()
    elif seleccion == '3':
        calculo_moda()
    elif seleccion == '4':
        calculo_varianza()
    elif seleccion == '5':
        calculo_desviacion()
    elif seleccion == '6':
        salir()
        break

    else:
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print("¡La opcion es incorrecta!... \n Por favor pulsa una opcion correcta para continuar: ")
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")```

*Sin embargo cuando lo compilo le arroja este error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Datos de usuario\Desktop\Python 3\Practicas con librerias de python\proyecto.py", line 67, in <module>
    calculo_media()
  File "D:\Datos de usuario\Desktop\Python 3\Practicas con librerias de python\proyecto.py", line 35, in calculo_media
    media = np.mean(datos)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in mean
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3372, in mean
    return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 160, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

*
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el error es por el tipo de dato que estás utilizando para la variable `dato` en la que recibes una entrada a través de `input`. Luego de esto haces un `append` a la variable global `datos` que más adelante utilizas para realizar operaciones.

**¿Qué sucede con `input` para realizar operaciones numéricas?**

Con `input` todo lo que ingresas será de tipo `string` con lo que no podrás realizar operaciones numéricas, como por ejemplo operaciones aritméticas (suma, resta, multiplicación, división), etc.

**Intenta cambiar la siguiente línea del código**:

```
dato = input("valor: ")
```

**Por**:

```
dato = int(input("valor: "))
```

Con esto, si necesitas que sean valores enteros podrías solucionar.

Luego podrías usar `numpy`. Veo que llamas a métodos a través de `np` y tengas seguramente un `import numpy as np` para importar `numpy`.

Si necesitas la variable global `datos` para realizar alguna operación con un método de `numpy` y necesitas que sean enteros, puedes hacer la conversión con el método `astype`:

```
datos.astype(int)
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Adrian! modificando el ingreso del input con int pude resolver el problema que venia teniendo!

Comment: Me alegro haberte ayudado.